# Display a round percent indicator with CSS only

Tags: html, safari, css, mobile-safari

[image: screenshot]

Hi all !

I want to create a small round static percent indicator in CSS but I can't find the solution.
The squared indicator at left is ok, but so ugly, I want it round !

I have tried with rounded corner (cf indicators at the right of the screenshot), and I wonder if there is possibility to add a rounded mask to hide the corners (cf. css3 mask : http://webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/), but it seems like it's only for img...

The solution can works only on webkit browsers, because it's for a mobile webapp.

Here is my code to create the (ugly) indicator in the image above :

```
<div class="meter-wrap">
     <div class="meter-value" style="background-color: #489d41; width: 70%;">
            <div class="meter-text"> 70 % </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

And the css :

```
.meter-wrap{
    position: relative;
}
.meter-value {
 
 background-color: #489d41;
 
}
.meter-wrap, .meter-value, .meter-text {
    width: 30px; height: 30px;
/* Attempt to round the corner : (indicators at the right of the screenshot)
-webkit-border-radius : 15px;*/
}
.meter-wrap, .meter-value {
    background: #bdbdbd top left no-repeat;
}          
.meter-text {
    position: absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
    padding-top: 2px;         
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
 font-size: 40%;
 text-shadow: #fffeff 1px 1px 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a round progress indicator? Usually, progress is linear, then reaches the end, so that lends itself to a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a wrapper around your `.meter-value` class, set its `overflow` to `hidden` and then set the width of that layer to get the desired effect. The rounded corners on the `.meter-value` class should remain intact and give you a nice fluid progress indicator.

You will have to move the `.meter-text` div outside of the wrapper to ensure it's visible throughout the transition, so your html would like something like:

```
<div class="meter-wrap">    
    <div class="meter-text"> 70 % </div>  
    <div class="meter-value-wrapper" style="width:70%;">
        <div class="meter-value" style="background-color: #489d41;">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the class for `.meter-value-wrapper` might look like:

```
.meter-value-wrapper { 
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 30px; 
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I don't want a dynamic progress indicator. It's more a visual and static pourcent indicator.
The squared indicator at left is ok, but so ungly, I want it round !

Sorry if my question wasn't explicit.

Comment: The example above will work for both. To create a static percent indicator just set the width of the .meter-value-wrapper class.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris, it works like a charm. Sorry for my first answer, I am too tired to think after 10h+ of work (it's 11pm in France ;-) )